# C6385 : reading invalid data. the readable size is x*4bytes, but '8'bytes may be read? Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++

I googled and learned that I need to use 'delete' for 'new()' and 'delete[] for 'new[]' in order to free dynamically allocated memory. 
Fortunately, my program doesn't crash and seems to run okay, but still gives me an error message
saying, "C6385 : reading invalid data. the readable size is objectCount*4bytes, but '8'bytes may be read."

I created an array of pointers - Part**Pptr = new Part*[objectsCount];
and by knowing pointer is 4 bytes in size, I understand "the readable size is objectCount*4bytes" this part. but I am wondering why the compiler says "8 bytes may be read", should I just ignore it? and also wondering if my program is getting memory leak regarding the error message.

this is my main.
I dynamically allocated objects with Pptr in store() funciton.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    int objectsCount = 0;
    myfile.open("Parts_ListPoly.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        howManyObjects(myfile, objectsCount);

        Parts** Pptr = new Parts *[objectsCount];

        store(myfile, Pptr, objectsCount);
        sortNetProfit(Pptr, objectsCount);
        print(Pptr, objectsCount);

        for(int i = 0; i < objectsCount; i++)
        { 
            delete Pptr[i]; // C6385 : reading invalid data. the readable size is objectsCount * 4bytes, but '8'bytes may be read?
        }
        delete[] Pptr;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file not opened" << endl;
    }
        myfile.close();
}
```

this is part of store() function.
Objects of derived classes are created(an object of 'Oil' in this case) dynamically and polymorphically with Pptr[i].
I think as Pptr[i] is a pointer, the size of it should be 4 bytes too?

```
void store(ifstream& myfile, Parts** Pptr, int &objectsCount)
{
    myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg); // set pointer at the beginning of the file  
    string line;
    string tokens[19];

    getline(myfile, line); // remove the first line

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsCount; i++)
    {
        getline(myfile, line);
        parseLineToTokens(line, tokens);

        // allocate the address of a derived object to each pointer from a pointer array
        try
        {
            if (tokens[0] == "Oil")
            {
                Pptr[i] = new Oil(tokens[0], tokens[1], convertFloat(tokens[2]), Manufacturer(tokens[3]), convertInt(tokens[4]), 
                    Car(tokens[5], tokens[6], convertInt(tokens[7])), Discount(tokens[15], tokens[16], tokens[17], convertFloat(tokens[18])), 
                    tokens[10], tokens[11], convertInt(tokens[12]));
            }
        ...
```

this is one of my derived class

```
class Oil : public Parts
{
public:
    Oil(string iWeight, string iType, int iQuarts)
        : weight(iWeight), type(iType), quarts(iQuarts)
    {}
    Oil(string iCategory, string iDescription, float iPrice, Manufacturer iManufacturer, int iQtySold, Car iCar, Discount iDiscount,
        string iWeight, string iType, int iQuarts)
        :Parts(iCategory, iDescription, iPrice, iManufacturer, iQtySold, iCar, iDiscount), weight(iWeight), type(iType), quarts(iQuarts)
    {}
    string getWeight() const;
    string getType() const;
    int getQuarts() const;
    virtual float calGrossProfit() const;
    virtual float calTotalCost() const;
    virtual float calNetProfit() const;

protected:
    std::string weight;
    std::string type;
    int quarts;
};
```

thank you very much

Comment: You probably need to use ```delete[] Pptr[i]``` instead of ```delete```.

Comment: Roy2511// thanks for the answer. but if I do that, then my program crashes.

Comment: Please show a [mre]